# Accessing property from class - php

Tags: php, laravel, oop, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am currently using pimax for facebook messenger: https://github.com/pimax/fb-messenger-php

I would like to access the `first_name` field from the class `UserProfile` in `UserProfile.php` and store it in a variable so that I can use the name for personalizing messages to users. I am having a hard time doing that without breaking the bot and would appreciate your help!

Here's the `UserProfile.php` file:

```
<?php
namespace pimax;

class UserProfile
{
    protected $data = [];

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->data['first_name'];
    }

    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->data['last_name'];
    }

    public function getPicture()
    {
        return $this->data['profile_pic'];
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Where do you create an instance of this class? Ex. `$up = new UserProfile($data); $up->getFirstName();`
You would of course need to supply the $data array yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've created your object like this:

```
// data is an associative array of user info that includes 'first_name' key
$user = new UserProfile($data);
```

You can extract the first name with:

```
$fname = $user->getFirstName();
```